# What is wrong with this charcode boolean statement?

Tags: javascript

I have an if/else statement inside a class object. The if checks a boolean statement, but returns the wrong result.

```
function person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = (function age() {
        if (this.name.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) <= "n".charCodeAt(0)) {
            return "A";
        }
        else {
            return "B";
        }
    })();
}

var zoey = new person("Zoey");


console.log(zoey.name);
console.log(zoey.age);  // returns A

console.log("Zoey".toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0));  // returns 122
console.log("n".charCodeAt(0));  // returns 110
```

It works if I change "this.name" inside the boolean statement to just "name". Any idea why?

Comment: Not too sure, but I think it has something to do with your scope. `(function age(){` creates a new scope and `this` may no longer refer to the `person` class. Name works because name is being passed into the class.

Comment: Is class name shouldn't be written from big letter, I mean `Person` instead of `person`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not holding its context. In fact, you are creating a new one by using the function. There are two ways around this:

```
var me = this;
me.name = name;
me.age = (function() {
    return me.name.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) <= "n".charCodeAt(0) ? "A" : "B";
})();
```

OR:

```
this.name = name;
this.age = (function() {
    return this.name.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) <= "n".charCodeAt(0) ? "A" : "B";
}).call(this);
```

Actually, three: just remove the `this.` inside the function and let the `name` variable from the scope above be used instead.

Comment: +1 That `call` looks nicer than my `bind` solution, didn't think about this.

Comment: Thank you, read up about call so now I understand apply and call.

Answer (score 5):

Your immediately invoked function expression is creating a new scope where the context of `this` changes. When you use just `name` you're referring to the parameter passed into the constructor. You can either cache `this` or `bind` it to maintain the context:

```
var self = this;
this.age = (function age() {
  if (self.name...)
}());

// In modern browsers
this.age = (function age() {
  if (this.name...)
}.bind(this)());
```

Comment: I'm glad even though I didn't really know why, I was right. Your clarification helps.

Comment: How would you use bind in an even further nested statement?

function Person(firstName, lastName, work, home, crimes) {
    this.crimes = (function criminal() {
        var policeRecord = "";
        (for (var p=0; p<this.crimes.length; ++p) {
            policeRecord += this.crimes[p] + ", ";
        }.bind(this));
        return policeRecord;
    }).call(this);
}

Comment: You can keep binding `this` every nested function but in that case it's better to use the `self = this` and use `self` instead of `this` in nested functions, it'll look cleaner.